# Get amount of bytes available in socket/file-descriptor with python

Tags: python, sockets, posix, file-descriptor

POSIX C

```
int bytes_available;
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available);
```

How to do the same in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function [`fcntl.ioctl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl) in [`fcntl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html) standard library and it internally uses the [`ioctl` system call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9684fac5a158be9806304a676e619857520a4dc/Modules/fcntlmodule.c#L270).

From the documentation,

> **fcntl.ioctl(fd, request, arg=0, mutate_flag=True)** This function is
> identical to the fcntl() function, except that the argument handling
> is even more complicated.
>
> The request parameter is limited to values that can fit in 32-bits.
> Additional constants of interest for use as the request argument can
> be found in the [`termios` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/termios.c#L742), under the same names as used in the
> relevant C header files.
>
> The parameter arg can be one of an integer, an object supporting the
> read-only buffer interface (like bytes) or an object supporting the
> read-write buffer interface (like bytearray).
>
> In all but the last case, behaviour is as for the fcntl() function.
>
> If a mutable buffer is passed, then the behaviour is determined by the
> value of the mutate_flag parameter.
>
> If it is false, the buffer’s mutability is ignored and behaviour is as
> for a read-only buffer, except that the 1024 byte limit mentioned
> above is avoided – so long as the buffer you pass is at least as long
> as what the operating system wants to put there, things should work.
>
> If mutate_flag is true (the default), then the buffer is (in effect)
> passed to the underlying ioctl() system call, the latter’s return code
> is passed back to the calling Python, and the buffer’s new contents
> reflect the action of the ioctl(). This is a slight simplification,
> because if the supplied buffer is less than 1024 bytes long it is
> first copied into a static buffer 1024 bytes long which is then passed
> to ioctl() and copied back into the supplied buffer.
>
> If the ioctl() fails, an OSError exception is raised.
>
> An example:
>
> ```
> >>> import array, fcntl, struct, termios, os
> >>> os.getpgrp()
> 13341
> >>> struct.unpack('h', fcntl.ioctl(0, termios.TIOCGPGRP, "  "))[0] 
> 13341
> >>> buf = array.array('h', [0])
> >>> fcntl.ioctl(0, termios.TIOCGPGRP, buf, 1) 
> 0
> >>> buf 
> array('h', [13341])
> ```